# Use both SIFT and SURF algorithms

Tags: opencv

I have indexed a large database with Sift and Surf and stored the descriptors in each case and I would like to use simultaneously both of them such as in http://www.ijarcce.com/upload/2016/si/nCORETech-16/nCORETech%207.pdf ,page 41, fig4.

I don't really know how to do this in practice.

Comment: Concatenate the SIFT and SURF descriptors? SIFT is 128 bits, SURF is 64 or 128 bits depending if `extended` or not. Final descriptor is 128+64 or 128+128 bits.

Comment: @Catree thanks for your comment but how concatenate the descriptors ? Do you have a piece of code with openCV ?

Comment: Create a new matrix with the good size and fill the concatenated descriptors with descriptor_sift and descriptor_surf. You should find some tutorial about how to iterate through a `mat` in [http://docs.opencv.org/](http://docs.opencv.org/). Other option is to use `hconcat` (search this function in the doc).