# run k-means on combination of SURF and SIFT descriptors in matlab

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, k-means, sift, surf

how can I combine SURF and SIFT descriptors in MATLAB in which SIFT is 128D and SURF is 64D and their number of descriptors are different and the other point is that the value of SURF descriptors are very very smaller than SIFT and some of them are negative while all sift descriptors are positive; and then run k-means on the combination of them?
there is a related duscussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43717704/use-both-sift-and-surf-algorithms/54063309?noredirect=1#comment94959969_54063309) but I couldn't understand it and that answer was for OpenCv

any help is appreciated

Comment: What is the problem in the concatenating of these two vectors (a vector with the size of 128D + 64D = 192D)? please explain more about your problem.

Comment: why do you sum dimentions?, I thought I should concatenate the matrix of SIFT (name it M) with matrix of SURF(name it N). so I have a concatenation like [128*m, 64*n] in which m is number of sift descriptors and n is number of surf descriptors. so the final matrix is not 192D!. I don't know how you cancatenate them in matlab and why its new dime is 192. I thought I should add ad 64*n matrix below surf matrix to make it 128D and then concatenate it with sift horizontally and get a 128D new matrix!.
i'm confused :D, can you explain it in matlab code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution can be transforming the result of these two descriptors to a unified size and then concatenate them easily. For example, using PCA to transform both of them into a 32D dimension SIFT (`32 * m` as `M_prime`) and SURF (`32*n` as `N_prime`) and concatenating them like this: `combined_feature_vectors = [M_prime N_prime]`. Hence, you have + n` descriptor with the size of 32.

You might solve the problem of small values for SURF by normalizing the features of each algorithm.

Comment: thanks I will try it, yeah I normalized them but still there is a little bit distance between values of them, for example sift is 0.01 and surf is -0.001 . nayway I will try them to see if I get a good result or not

Comment: I reduced sift dime into 64 and then combined them. but I didn't get results approved. I had read about it that if I combine them I should get better results. thanks anyways